# Thymeleaf login form not being processed by Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf, form-processing

I have the following thymeleaf login.html form and I am trying to check if username and password match the ones in the database, but when I click on Login it redirects to http://localhost:8080/login?error=true without processing it in the login() method.

**Here is the HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="align">

    <div class="grid">

        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" th:object="${loginForm}" class="form login">

            <br/>
            <div class="form__field">
                <label for="username"><svg class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#user"></use></svg><span class="hidden">Username</span></label>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form__input" placeholder="Username" autofocus="autofocus" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form__field">
                <label for="password"><svg class="icon"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#lock"></use></svg><span class="hidden">Password</span></label>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form__input" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>

             <div th:if="${error}">
                <div class="alert alert-info">Username or Password are wrong</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form__field">
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Security configurations:**

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }
```

**Controller method login() for POST mapping:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name="loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, Model model, BindingResult result) {

    String username = loginForm.getUsername();
    String password = loginForm.getPassword();
    String page = "";
    Boolean exists;
    exists = userService.usernameExists(username);
    if(exists) {
        User u = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if(u.getPassword().contentEquals(password)) {
            if(u.getRole().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {
                page = "userpage";
            } else {
                page = "adminpage"; 
            }
        }   
    } else {
         model.addAttribute("error", true); 
         page = "login";  
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        page = "login";    
    }

    return page;
}
```

**This is the LoginForm class:**

```
public class LoginForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    public LoginForm() {}

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

Is there any problem with what I've written so far which might cause the form not to processed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't be writing your own controller to handle logins. For example, it appears you're storing passwords in plaintext! Use Spring Security instead, and it automatically handles the `POST /login` endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I read that somewhere, but even when I did not have the controller, it would still do the same thing.

Comment: Correct: Spring Security is handling it before it gets dispatched to Spring MVC. You need to read the Getting Started Guides on Spring Security, since you're attempting to use it.